# Setting default option values for third-party modules

Tags: cmake

I am using CMake for my project and I am relying on a number of different third-party libraries, who themselves use CMake.

Many of them provide `Options` in their main CMake such as -

```
option(GLM_QUIET "No CMake Message" OFF)
option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build shared library" ON)
option(BUILD_STATIC_LIBS "Build static library" ON)
option(GLM_TEST_ENABLE_CXX_98 "Enable C++ 98" OFF)

option ( ASSIMP_BUILD_ASSIMP_TOOLS
  "If the supplementary tools for Assimp are built in addition to the library."
  ON
)
option ( ASSIMP_BUILD_SAMPLES
  "If the official samples are built as well (needs Glut)."
  OFF
)
```

I want to set some of these options to be different than their original values when I include them by default.

I tried setting them like this before including the main CMakes -

```
SET( ASSIMP_BUILD_ASSIMP_TOOLS OFF )
```

But then I get this error from CMake:

```
CMake Warning (dev) at Thirdparty/glm/CMakeLists.txt:14 (option):
  Policy CMP0077 is not set: option() honors normal variables.  Run "cmake
  --help-policy CMP0077" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to
  set the policy and suppress this warning.

  For compatibility with older versions of CMake, option is clearing the
  normal variable 'ASSIMP_BUILD_ASSIMP_TOOLS '.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

If I try to do this -

```
OPTION( ASSIMP_BUILD_ASSIMP_TOOLS OFF )
```

It just quietly ignores it.

What is the correct way to deal with this?

Comment: You either set the variable as a cache entry or enable CMP0077 to enable the new behavior and `SET( ASSIMP_BUILD_ASSIMP_TOOLS OFF )` should have worked as expected.